# How to clear screen in both windows and linux in C

Tags: c, linux

For the second part of my project I'm trying to clear the screen after each operation using `system("clear");`.

This works fine but my teacher/lecturer works with windows and they get the following message in the console when they reach the `cls`:

> `'clear' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.`

In that case I would have to change the `system("clear")` to `system("cls");`.

Is there anyway that I can check the OS and get the program to switch between `"cls"` and '"clear"`?

Here is my code:

```
printf("Please provide name: \n");
scanf("%[^\n]s", contact_name);
getchar();
system("clear");
printf("Please provide contact number: \n");
scanf("%[^\n]s", tel_num);
getchar();
system("clear");
// items
printf("\t\t\t\t  Our Apparels: \n");
printf("\t\t\tApparels\t\tItem code\n");
printf("\t\t\ta)T-Shirts\t\t'T'\n");
printf("\t\t\tb)Bags\t\t\t'B'\n");
printf("\t\t\tc)Caps\t\t\t'C'\n\n");
printf("Enter corresponding item code: \n");
scanf(" %c", & code);
// reading item code
while (code != 'T' && code != 'B' && code != 'C') {
  printf("Enter corresponding item code: \n");
  scanf(" %c", & code);
  getchar();
  system("clear");
}
```

Comment: Downvote for not searching about whether this kind of question was asked before. Delevago1999, please do your research next time.

Comment: this link didn't answer my question. the answer below did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this instead:

```
system("clear | cls")
```

You could also try using two pipes (`||`) instead of one (`|`), like this:

```
system("clear || cls")
```